# Do I have to pass all 4 listed exam to become MCM

Tags: certification

Here are the exams for SharePoint Professionals:

- 70-573 TS: Microsoft SharePoint 2010, Application Development
- 70-667 TS: Microsoft Office SharePoint 2010, Configuring
- 70-576 PRO: Designing and Developing Microsoft SharePoint 2010
  Applications
- 70-668 PRO: Microsoft SharePoint 2010, Administrator

I want to be a SharePoint architect and also a MCM so do I have to pass all of above exams to become MCM.

**EDIT**

Sorry I meant MCM not MCP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft Certified Master (MCM) for SharePoint 2010, is a high-end and exclusive training available for SQL Server, Active Directory, Lync Server, Exchange Server and SharePoint Server. The training is normally a three week course, held  in Redmond, tutored by the most skilled people on the respective product. First of all you need to pass several steps to even get into the program, then you need to pay the huge fee and then finally get out of the classroom with three exams and a qualification lab alive. If you need more information about the program, head on over to the [MCM/MCA site](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/master.aspx).

Here are more details on becoming [SharePoint MCM](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/master-sharepoint.aspx). And one of the requirement of the program is that you have to pass **all 4 SharePoint 2010 exams** :)

> Candidates must have passed the following exams prior to applying to
>   the program :

1. Exam 70-573: TS: Microsoft SharePoint 2010, Application Development
2. Exam 70-576: PRO: Designing and Developing Microsoft SharePoint 2010
   Applications
3. Exam 70-667: TS: Microsoft SharePoint 2010,
   Configuring
4. Exam 70-668: PRO: SharePoint 2010, Administrator

Comment: The exam format has changed slightly - it is now just one longer knowledge exam plus the qual. lab.

Comment: ah I just remember that you hold MCM, please feel free to share your experiences. I am planning to do it next year :)

Comment: Great! You might be interested in my blog post about my experiences: http://www.spdoctor.net/Pages/article.aspx?name=SharePoint-2010-MCM. Good luck with your MC(S)M.

Answer (score 2):

**70-573 TS: Microsoft SharePoint 2010, Application Development

70-576 PRO: Designing and Developing Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Applications**

These make you MCP in Development

**70-667 TS: Microsoft Office SharePoint 2010, Configuring
 70-668 PRO: Microsoft SharePoint 2010, Administrator**

These make you MCP in Administration

As per my knowledge!

Comment: thanks, sorry I meant MCM not MCP & I also added you on skype :)

Comment: what is MCM by the way? yeah, no prob on adding on skype! :)

Comment: mcm is microsoft certified master

Answer (score 0):

I would not word the question like that.  You have to pass all 4 exams to even qualify to be considered attending a 3 week rotation.  You also need to read about 100 articles of content ranging from whitepapers to whole books.  You will never get past the "interview" if you haven't done your homework before applying for the class.  It's Microsoft's top level certification and it's not easy.  Think of it like a really compressed graduate program.  You are getting your Master's in SharePoint Technology.  You don't "just" walk into a university and goto to graduate level classes and get your advanced degree.  You first need your undergraduate degree and decent scores on your GRE.  These are equivalent to the professional level certifications in SharePoint offered by Microsoft.